# Can anybody tell me what does this sentence mean "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them."

Tags: sentence-meaning, british-english, indian-english, spoken-english

can anybody explain me what does the sentence mean "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them."

Comment: Don't select your answer in hurry. At times, you may get better answers and other learners can know the thoughts of native speakers regarding your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MW Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/air),

> air of mystery: a mysterious quality

The statement you have given above means to convey the following:

> "It appears that this user likes to be mysterious. The user may not wish to disclose details regarding himself/herself and thus prefers to be mysterious. It could mean that there is a lot more to the user than meets the eye, but he/she prefers to be quiet about it. *At the same time, it is sometimes intended to generate curiosity and intrigue about the person.*